How do I avoid NullReferenceException when user-agent is absent from ASP.NET MVC (Umbraco) app?
TryBooking is calling my URL, but no longer passing through a user-agent. Postman shows the same error when calling the URL with no user-agent:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
FileMappingModule.MapContent.Is_spider() +155
FileMappingModule.MapContent.Context_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +184
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +222
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +219
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93

How do I turn off the spider check, or pre-fill the incoming header?
I've tried fiddling with ActionFilterAttribute but that makes no difference.

Where is FileMappingModule coming from?

I have no idea?
